# Why does MTP show wrong directory location?

Tags: usb, storage, bugs, mtp, media-scanner

MTP (*Miserable Transfer Protocol*) failed once again.

After moving a directory to a different path, it is still on the same path as before according to MTP.

I already tried re-plugging the USB port and reading it from a different computer. Same result.

Why is MTP so bogus that it shows a moved folder on its previous path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is Content Provider?**

It seems to be a problem related to Media Providers. As the name suggests, they provide a database of available media in a more organized way to other apps as the `Contacts Storage` (*com.android.providers.contacts*) provides contacts to requesting apps. Purpose is to scan and store media file info for quick access so that individual apps don't have to scan folders manually for an up-to-date library, reducing time and effort.

**Android's built-in Media Providers:**

Some file explorers, media players and gallery apps depend on the files database (*/data/data/com.android.providers.media/databases/external.db*) built by `Media Storage` app for [MediaStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html) content provider from the contents of external storage (`/sdcard` and external SD card; removable storage like USB isn't indexed). Apps `Media Storage` (*com.android.providers.media* under which *com.process.media* runs), `Downloads` (*com.android.providers.downloads.ui*), `Download Manager` (*com.android.providers.downloads*) and `MTP Host` (*com.android.mtp*) work in collaboration under same UID.

Database is built/updated as `MediaScanner` (*android.process.media*) is invoked by some app such as by sending broadcast [MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE) or through [scanFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). Broadcast receiver `com.android.providers.media.MediaScannerReceiver` is launched on boot that listens for [android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED), so MediaScannerService will also launch on boot. But restarting phone sometimes doesn't update whole external database (or at least delays). MediaScanner is also triggered when a new storage device is mounted i.e. on [MEDIA_MOUNTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED) which could possibly be [manually broadcasted](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51800/218526) to force updation on pre KitKat versions.
In response, apps are informed of updated databases such as by receiving broadcast [MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED) or through [onScanCompleted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient.html#onScanCompleted(java.lang.String,%20android.net.Uri)).

**Problem with Media Providers:**

[MtpService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/MediaProvider/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/providers/media/MtpService.java) is also a part of Media Storage. Due to some bugs ([acknowledged since 2012](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956498)) in implementation of MTP, database isn't updated or is delayed or isn't properly communicated with the client as the files change, so MTP shows outdated / incomplete contents. The same can happen if an app creating or downloading a new file fails to trigger the MediaScanner or fails to receive back the updated information.

**Solution:**

In order to force database updation, delete the file and run some [media scanner](https://github.com/zhuowei/scanmediaplz) app. Non-root users can delete this file by clearing data of `Media Storage` app.
But be aware, it'll also clear `internal.db` which will make ringtones unavailable and a new database will be built from `/system/media` on next reboot i.e. on `BOOT_COMPLETED`.

**PS:** Note that the internal SD card we see is [emulated](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526) from `/data/media/` using `sdcardfs` (or `FUSE` in older versions of Android). Actual contents of internal memory can be seen directly from `/data/media/` (root required). [UMS](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-trusty-3.10/Documentation/usb/mass-storage.txt) used to expose the `/data` block device to PC but was deprecated in favor of MTP. It's a good option when larger size of data is to be transferred at high speeds. It can be enabled by [some workaround](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526).
There are also other reasonable alternatives for MTP like FTP, SFTP/SSHFS, [adbfs](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless) etc.

**RESOURCES:**

- [How Android categorizes files based on their extensions](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/210294/218526)
- [MTP, External Storage, and Your App](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/08/31/mtp-external-storage.html)
- [Scan Media Files In Android](https://droidyue.com/blog/2014/01/19/scan-media-files-in-android/)
- [Broadcasts overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts)
- [Android Content Providers](http://mrbool.com/android-content-provider-how-to-use-content-provider-for-data-access/30446)