# Camera folder displayed as empty, but contains 20GB data

Tags: internal-storage, camera, file-system, file-management

My Lenovo Moto G5 Plus' internal storage ran full, and now there appears to be a problem with the photos that are saved on its internal storage. The internal DCIM/Camera folder is displayed as empty when I

- open the gallery app
- open the folder with the Solid Explorer app
- open the folder on my PC (file transfer mode as well as PTP mode).

BUT the app "DiskUsage" says that the folder has got a size of 20GB, and luckily I was able to do a backup of its contents using `adb pull`.

What can I do to make the content visible for the phone again? Using a scanning app like "SD Card scanner" did not help.

Comment: Try clearing data of `Media Storage` app: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526

Comment: delete .nomedia files