# How much of the Android filesystem is visible over MTP?

Tags: file-system, mtp, file-permissions

When I plug in my Android device to my computer it gets connected as a media device under `MTP` mode. I can browse a bit of the folders on my device via my computer. I'm wondering how much of the device am I actually able to see? What sort of folders and content specifically is *not* visible over MTP? Does MTP have a corresponding set of file permissions associated with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MTP - an extension to PTP - is a client-server protocol, roughly like FTP. MTP client on PC sends operation requests (like GET_OBJECT, SEND_OBJECT, DELETE_OBJECT) to server running on Android device and gets responses back.

Unlike USB Mass Storage (UMS), MTP doesn't expose filesystem at all. Instead contents of shared external storage (`/sdcard` - a subdirectory of `/data/media/` - and physically external SD card) which are indexed in database of `MediaStore` Content Provider are shown to PC. Everything else (including `/data`, `/system`, `/vendor` and other filesystems) is not visible over MTP.

Since there's no filesystem level access, there're no filesystem permissions. Related details:

- [Why does MTP show wrong directory location?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526)
- [Android Storage Journey](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218469/218526)
- [What is /storage/emulated/0/?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205494/218526)
- [Android Device Partitions and Filesystems](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/info-android-device-partitions-basic-t3586565)

Comment: does rooting the Android make the filesystem more visible externally (like on a laptop)?

Comment: Rooting itself does not expose the filesystem over USB. But it gives you the power to do so by [enabling UMS](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526).

Comment: Do I need to be rooted to enable UMS?