# How to mount Andoid 10 file system on Ubuntu 20?

Tags: usb, linux

On the phone, I did

> Settings --> Developer Options --> Default USB Configuration -->
> Transferring files / Android Auto

Hoping that would mount its filesystem on `Ubuntu 20` when connected USB. But it didn't, at least it doesn't show in the file browser.

Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: See [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526) and [How much of the Android filesystem is visible over MTP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225172/218526)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205251/why-cant-i-see-android-storage-as-a-partition-on-pc)

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can mount it the same way as Android 9 on Ubuntu 18 (or any Android > 4 on almost any Linux distribution) – utilizing ADB. I use **[adbfs-rootless](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless)** for that. True, you need to compile it yourself – but that's pretty easy, with instructions in the readme. That done you can easily mount the storage of your Android device at the command line – and access everything that's accessible without root powers as if it were locally available on your Linux machine.