# How do I clean up remembered files in builtin files app?

Tags: sd-card, file-management, media-files

Default files app is showing many files (mostly photos) that don't exist anymore. How to clean it up?

All of these files existed under `/sdcard` and were cleaned via synchronization with my PC over ssh. I don't keep my old photos on my phone, and most of the rest was just junk.

(Yes the files really don't exist. If I tap them it just spins. It's like the files app can't handle the file not being there.)

I've operated this way for a long time, but it's glitched out now.

This is an rooted essential PH-1 phone; firmware is from this year. Note that rooted PH-1 phones run patched firmware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete cache of the file manager and photos app.
- Go to the app info section in your settings, enable "show system apps" on the hamburger menu, locate media storage, delete it's cache. Reboot, wait for a few minutes for the media databases to build up again and your problem most likely would be solved.
- This may not always solve the problem as explained very well in [this answer by Irfan Latif](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/131553) and you may have to resort using apps such as [AZ media rescan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobar.azmediascanner)