# If I plug a 1TB ssd drive to android phone via otg cable, will andorid system scan all media files in the drive?

Tags: external-sd, usb-on-the-go

I concern about performance a lot. Thus I have this question. If I plug a 1TB ssd drive to android phone via otg cable, will andorid system scan all media files in the drive automatically once it gets mounted? Will this cause any performance issue and add more CPU/RAM overhead? If it does it, how to stop this behavior? I just want the system scan the media files when I open a particular folder which contains the media files. I don't really want the system to scan everything before I actually want to access them. Thanks a lot.

Comment: While writing [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526) I checked the source code which indicates that Android's `MediaScanner` doesn't scan USB OTG storage devices.