# How to resolve a bug where documets and media files are not indexed to MediaStorage

Tags: file-management, miui, media-files, media-scanner

I have encountered a problem with several file managers which I have failed to resolve.

Files in my device are not properly indexed and hence are not recognised by the file managers at least to my understanding.

Instead of choosing a desired category in the file manager e.g documents or video etc, it shows as empty yet  have several files of that type. I have to manually dig through the internal Storage to find the specific file see image:

[image]

I understand in some devices running MIUI, the culprit apps usually are Downloads and MediaStorage so I have wiped their data and even uninstalled updates yet the problem still persists. Funny the problem does not in second space (multi user space), anything that I am missing.

*Android 9, MIUI 11 Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 (mido)*

Comment: Have you tried a force scan of shared storage: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209119/218526?

Comment: files in second space probably have different location (or namespace) if your phone is rooted check /data/media/0 /data/media/10 ... possible other reason files placed /data/media/0 manually may not have right permissions. files with non-trivial names (forbidden chars on fat) or size bigger than 4gb are invisible from /storage/emulated/0

Comment: @IrfanLatif yes I did a force scan twice but with no positive results

Comment: it's hard to say without knowing file location and how the file was created or if we even talk about the same thing. for example on isolated mount namespaces you can create a file from one app but it is not visible to other apps, unless you change settings in magisk

Comment: @alecxs thanks so much for the explanation, the problem is fixed after a nandroid restoration, I don't whether I should delete this question or leave  as it seems too individualised.

Comment: @xavier_fakerat don't delete the question. Post the answer as something like: "I restored nandroid backup I had and it solved the problem for me. It is unfortunate that I still don't know how restoring the backup solved the problem. If anyone has pointers to that, please put them in the  comments for others to understand this solution". A lot of times, an answer has good value even if it doesn't explain how the answer works. :)